# Why does $(1 + x)^{1/x} $ approach $e$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Tags: limits

For smaller and smaller values of x in the expression $(1 + x)^{1/x} $, its value seems to approach the constant $e$,

- $(1 + 1E-10)^{1E10} = 2.71828182832313114395...   $
- $(1 + 1E-20)^{1E20} = 2.718281828459045235347$

but how can it be proven that:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1 + x)^{1/x}  = e$$

I was first introduced to e with this definition

$$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x$$

Comment: The number $e$ was designed in order for this to work.

Comment: What is your definition for $e$?

Comment: To some,
$$e=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1t\right)^t.$$
To others,
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n.$$
Others say
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$
and some say $e$ is the number with
$$\int_1^e\frac {dx}x=1.$$
There are still more opinions. What's $e$ to you?

Comment: I was first introduced to e with this def d(e^x) /dx = e^x

Comment: @Chrystomath I don't think it is a valid duplicate since here we need to start from $\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use binomial expansion:

$$f(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}=1+x\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{x}-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{x}-2)}{3!}x^3+\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{x}-2)(\frac{1}{x}-3)}{4!}x^4+...$$
$$f(x)=1+1+\frac{(1-x)}{2!}+\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)}{3!}+\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)}{4!}+...$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+...= e$$

Comment: How do you justify that the limit $x \to 0$ of the infinity series can be taken term-wise?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. With L'Hospital show that $ \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0.$
2. We have $(1+x)^{1/x}= e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}.$

Answer (score 2):

No L'Hospital's rule required for this: it approaches $\:\mathrm e\:$ because its log approaches 1. Indeed
$$\ln\bigl( (1+x)^{1/x}\bigr)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln 1}{(1+x)-1}\xrightarrow{\text{ def }}\ln'(1)=1.$$

Comment: Hi Bernard ! It is a good idea to provide here *les bons vieux trucs qui ont bercé notre jeunesse*. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I must say my first er answreflex woulld have been to answer ‘A moment's reflection shows it corresponds to the definition of the derivative of the log’… Totally unrelated: I've seen you live in Pau — I savoured recently a delicious Jurançon bio.

Comment: If, at any time, you are close to Pau, come here and you will drink a nectar (as many as you can - no doggie bag !). I hope and wish that this could happen ! Cheers :-).

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Now take $\ln$ (natural logarithm)  of both sides and since $\ln$ is continuous for $\mathbb R^{+}$ we have that

$$\ln(y)=\ln(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}})=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln((1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}})$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$$ and now by [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20calculus,be%20easily%20evaluated%20by%20substitution.) we have:

$$\ln(y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{1+x}=1$$

$$\implies \ln(y)=1$$

So $$y=e.$$

Alternatively consider the series representation $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Based on your definition by derivative we have that

$$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx}=e^x \iff\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{e^{x-x_0}-e^{x_0}}{x-x_0}=e^{x_0} \iff \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

therefore by $x=\log (1+y) \to 0$ with $y\to 0$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(1+y)-1}{\log(1+y)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{\log\left[(1+y)^\frac1y\right]}=1$$

that is

$$\lim_{y\to 0} (1+y)^\frac1y=e$$